# get dynamic text in text area on every click on div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to open the `CKEDITOR` on `click-event` of `div`, and want the div contents in that `textarea` of ckeditor
but somehow this is not working.

Thanks in advance, and sorry for my poor english

```
function createEditor() {

    $('DIV').click(function(event) {
        var id1 = event.target.id;
        //alert(id1);

        document.getElementById("editor1").value = '';
        var newtext = document.getElementById(id1).innerHTML;
        alert(newtext);
        document.getElementById("editor1").value += newtext;
    });

    document.getElementById("contents").style.display = "block";
}
```

Comment: "**somehow this is not working**" --> This is the part you need to elaborate :)

Comment: paste your corresponding html, and are you sure, you got just 1 div on whole page? There might be other div's as well.. and hence you see the unexpected results..

Comment: @mtk dude give me your mail id, so that i can send you the whole code, if you can get that much tym.. or look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rbPNV/15/

Answer (score 0):

Remove createEditor() function and try it

```
 $('DIV').click(function(event) {
    var id1 = event.target.id;
    //alert(id1);

    document.getElementById("editor1").value = '';
    var newtext = document.getElementById(id1).innerHTML;
    alert(newtext);
    document.getElementById("editor1").value += newtext;
});

document.getElementById("contents").style.display = "block";
```

Comment: try to use lilve() $("p").live("click", function(){
  alert("data");
});

Comment: @Nishant you are able to get into the click event function? what does the `alert` stmt say?

Comment: @mtk I am getting the div data into the alert, but that data is not getting replaced by textarea's value ..

Comment: <script>
$('DIV').live("click", function(event){
  var id1 = event.target.id;
    //alert(id1);

    document.getElementById("editor1").value = '';
    var newtext = document.getElementById(id1).innerHTML;
    alert(newtext);
    document.getElementById("editor1").value += newtext;
});
</script>

Comment: @dev thanks for your reply bro... but not working, dont even getting the id in alert...

Answer (score 0):

Try this to add data to the textarea.

```
$("#editor1").val(newtext);
```

or use

```
$('#editor1').append(newtext);
```

Comment: what does the broswer js console show? does it give any error... do check.

Comment: no it doesnt show any error, actually sometimes it displays value in textarea sometime not..

Answer (score 0):

This solution will rely more on jQuery. First, if you want this function to be triggered when ever a `div` is clicked, get rid of your `function()`, it's not necessary since your event will be triggered every time a `div` is clicked.

This should solve your problems:

```
$('div').click(function(e) {
    $id1 = $(this).attr("id");
    alert($id1);

   $("#editor1").val(' '); //Are you sure you want to empty your textarea?
   $newtext = $("#"+$id1).html();
   alert($newtext);
   $("#editor1").val($newtext); //Because when you append the newtext it won't append but replace the text it's already on this.

   $("#contents").css("display","block");
});
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brunovieira/6EM6A/) with a similar example of using your function:

Comment: thanks for the reply, but this script is giving alert as "Undefined" and "null"

Comment: Not in the fiddle, if this is happening on your code your error is somewhere else

Comment: Are you sure you have put your function inside the: `$(document).ready()` block?

Comment: nopes, actually i am trying to create a site that creates newsletters dynamically, so that it gives users to change and add new data from newsletter. this is just first step of my site

Comment: no i havent put this code into $(document).ready(), sorry bro but i am not a javascript guy, I am a core PHP guy, so i dont know much more about JS and JQuery

Comment: I am getting other Div's Ids and contents in alert, but the textarea value is not getting replaced, and ya the main div which i want to use shows "Undefined", this div is used in <tr><td> tag,.

Comment: hello there, I have also created a fiddle here if you get time than take a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/rbPNV/9/

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the text of the clicked div and you're using jQuery try

```
$("div").click( function() {
    var newtext = $(this).text();
    $("#editor1").text( newtext );
});
```